# Can you solve this error in the following code?

Tags: solidity, remix

Can you please solve this error in the following image ?

[image]

Comment: For future reference, please include code that can be copy+pasted by other users, rather than a picture :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code, mistake is `balances[msg.sender] -= uint;`. In solidity uint is a datatype/reserved words/keyword. So you can't assign datatype as a value. I guess its typo error.

You can optimize code. Refer require(), assert()

```
function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success){
    require(balances[msg.sender]>=tokens && tokens>=0);
    balances[msg.sender] -= tokens;
    balances[to] += tokens;
    return true;
}
```

No need to write if and else.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to help if you posted code instead of a picture.

```
if(balances[msg.sender] >= tokens && tokens > 0) {
  balances[msg.sender] -= tokens;
  balances[to] += tokens;
  return true;
}
else { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues: it's balances[to], not balances[address to]. And refer to the variables tokens as `tokens`, not `uint`.

```
function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success){
    if(balances[msg.sender]>=tokens && tokens>=0){
        balances[msg.sender] -= tokens;
        balances[to] += tokens;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```